# ZXing.Mobile - How to change the size of the camera scanner?

Tags: xamarin, configuration, xamarin.forms, zxing, barcode-scanner

**UPDATE:**

I've tried implementing this in an App.cs method called OpenCameraScanner (you would call this on click of a button on the page from which you want to scan):

```
App.cs
------------------------------------------------
public static ZXingScannerPage ScanPage;
public static ZXing.Result ScanResult;

public static async void OpenCameraScanner()
{
    ScanPage = new ZXingScannerPage(customOverlay: customOverlay);
    ScanPage.OnScanResult += (result) =>
    {
        ScanPage.IsScanning = false;
        ScanResult = result;

        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
        {
            App.CurrentApp.CurrentPage.Navigation.PopModalAsync();
            App.CurrentApp.CurrentPage.DisplayAlert("Scanned Barcode", result.Text, "OK");
        });
    };
    var scanPage = new NavigationPage(ScanPage);
    await App.CurrentApp.CurrentPage.Navigation.PushModalAsync(ScanPage);
}
```

However, when this method is called, the screen that opens is blank white, and you can't see the camera view behind it. Not sure why?

---

I'm using ZXing.Mobile in a Xamarin.Forms project (for iOS right now) for camera scanning functionality on an iPad.

Currently, I have it working great with the following 2 lines:

```
var scanner = new ZXing.Mobile.MobileBarcodeScanner();
var result = await scanner.Scan();
```

However, when the camera is open to scan, it takes up the entire iPad screen, which is really big.

**Question:** Is there a way to adjust the size of the camera overlay? (so that it's not full screen)

I see that the `scanner.Scan()` method takes an optional options parameter of type `ZXing.Mobile.MobileBarcodeScanningOptions` - I tried playing around with that, but the only possible relevant option there is a `CameraResolutionSelector` - but I'm having a really hard time finding any documentation on that.

Answer (score 3):

There is a ZXing sample app that shows how to embed the `ZXingScannerView` and `ZXingDefaultOverlay` into a `Xamarin.Form`'s `Grid`:

https://github.com/Redth/ZXing.Net.Mobile/blob/master/Samples/Forms/Core/CustomScanPage.cs

```
public CustomScanPage () : base ()
{
    zxing = new ZXingScannerView
    {
        HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
        VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
        AutomationId = "zxingScannerView",
    };
    zxing.OnScanResult += (result) => 
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread (async () => {

            // Stop analysis until we navigate away so we don't keep reading barcodes
            zxing.IsAnalyzing = false;

            // Show an alert
            await DisplayAlert ("Scanned Barcode", result.Text, "OK");

            // Navigate away
            await Navigation.PopAsync ();
        });

    overlay = new ZXingDefaultOverlay
    {
        TopText = "Hold your phone up to the barcode",
        BottomText = "Scanning will happen automatically",
        ShowFlashButton = zxing.HasTorch,
        AutomationId = "zxingDefaultOverlay",
    };
    overlay.FlashButtonClicked += (sender, e) => {
        zxing.IsTorchOn = !zxing.IsTorchOn;
    };
    var grid = new Grid
    {
        VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
        HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
    };
    grid.Children.Add(zxing);
    grid.Children.Add(overlay);

    // The root page of your application
    Content = grid;
}
```

Comment: I see, so it looks like I need to use a custom overlay (https://github.com/Redth/ZXing.Net.Mobile/blob/master/readme.md#custom-overlays)

Comment: @jbyrd You can use the default `ZXingDefaultOverlay` if you wish, if that does not match your app style, yes you can create a custom one.

Comment: I'm still a little confused with how this works, though - right now, all I have to do is call the 2 lines you see in my original post. With this, we're introducing a page (does Scan() basically open a page?). If I create a custom page, how do those 2 lines fit in...or do I have to do something entirely different?

Comment: @jbyrd `ZXingScannerView` is a `View`, so you can place it anywhere a `View` (button/label/...) can be placed, if that is in a new page within your UI design, or within a modal popup or inserted into an existing page, that is your choice.

Comment: I understand that, but take a step back; I'm asking a more fundamental question. Currently, I have a page with a "Start Camera Scan" button, and on click of that button, it executes `var scanner = new ZXing.Mobile.MobileBarcodeScanner();` and then `var result = await scanner.Scan();` - that's it! Soooo...to use a custom overlay, on button click, what do I do? Launch a whole new page - like the CustomScanPage() in your example? And that page has to contain the ZXingScannerView with OnScanResult code, etc.? I mean it's definitely doable; just seems like a lot for a custom view.

Comment: @jbyrd Yes, that example is a "new page", but it could be one of your existing pages and all you are doing is adding the `grid` to your existing layout.

Comment: I see! Looking at this page also helped me put it all together: https://github.com/Redth/ZXing.Net.Mobile/blob/0ec0cf47ccecf63ea9cb2721289397f080233333/Samples/Forms/Core/HomePage.cs. Thanks for pushing me in the right direction.

Comment: please see update to question, where I've posted code I've tried since the original post.